# Assistance with Proof of an Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove that $\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{n} \leq (a_1)^2+(a_2)^2+...+(a_n)^2$.

My approach was to use induction, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the inductive step. I also tried proving for when $n=2$, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Can someone guide me in the right direction for this problem? Is induction even the right way to approach it?

Thanks!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For $n=2$, it's essentially the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Comment: Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauchy - Schwarz inequality says $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k b_k \leq \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^{2}} \sqrt {\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^{2}}$. Your inequality is just the special case when $b_k=1$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Jensen’s inequality below to function $f(x) =x^2$.

$$f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\>...\>+f(x_n)\ge n f\left( \frac{x_1+x_2+\>...\>+x_n}{n}\right)$$

https://brilliant.org/wiki/jensens-inequality/

The inequality is due to the convex nature of the quadratic function $x^2$, but is not restrictive to the function $x^2$. It is true for any convex functions. Thus, the induction proof may not be a natural method.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $x_1^2+x_2^2 \ge 2x_1x_2$, its repeated use gives
$$(n-1)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+....+x_n^2) \ge 2(x_1 x_2+ x_2 x_3+,,,,,+x_{n-1} x_n).~~~~~~~(1)$$
or $$ 2(x_1 x_2+ x_2 x_3+,,,,,+x_{n-1} x_n) \le (n-1)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+....+x_n^2)~~~~~(2)
$$
Next $$(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)^2 = (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+....+x_n^2)+2(x_1 x_2+ x_2 x_3+,,,,,+x_{n-1} x_n~~~~~(3))$$
Adding (2) and (3) we gwt
$$(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)^2 \le n (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+....+x_n^2)~~~~~(4).$$